# PHP value passing to mail certain document with dynamic values

Tags: email, include, file-get-contents, php

I am looking to send a dynamic email based off of what selection they use in the form of the website. Currently I have:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlentities($_POST['name']) : '';
    $more_info = isset($_POST['more_info']) ? htmlentities($_POST['more_info']) : '';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Hello <hello@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$to_email = 'Me <hello@me.com>';

$subject_email = 'Test Contact';

if ($more_info == "A") { $mail_content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mail/a.php');}
if ($more_info == "B") { $mail_content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mail/b.php');}
if ($more_info == "C") { $mail_content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mail/c.php');}
if ($more_info == "D") { $mail_content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mail/d.php');}
if ($more_info == "E") { $mail_content = include('/mail/e.php');}

mail($to_email, $subject_email, $mail_content, $headers);
```

So i need to pass the $name, and other variables to send in the correct mail function when collected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this exactly what I was looking for.

I continued to do file_get_contents, but then i used at str_replace. I put the values I wanted to find in the array like:

```
$static_content = array('$a,$b,$c');
```

and then made it replace using:

```
$dynamic_content = array("$a,$b,$c");
```

put the whole thing together:

```
$mail_content = str_replace($static_content,$dyanmic_content,$mail_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlentities($_POST['name']) : '';
$more_info = isset($_POST['more_info']) ? htmlentities($_POST['more_info']) : '';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Hello <hello@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$to_email = 'Me <hello@me.com>';

$subject_email = 'Test Contact';

$mail_content = "Dear $name,\n\n";
$mail_content .= "$more_info";

if ($more_info == "A") { $mail_content .= file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mail/a.php');}
if ($more_info == "B") { $mail_content .= file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mail/b.php');}
if ($more_info == "C") { $mail_content .= file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mail/c.php');}
if ($more_info == "D") { $mail_content .= file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mail/d.php');}
if ($more_info == "E") { $mail_content .= include('/mail/e.php');}

mail($to_email, $subject_email, $mail_content, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rodney, but I am looking to pass values to PHP values in side example.com/mail/a.php. I might not have made that clear last time. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: @Dan In your example above, the defined variables $name and $more_info  will be available to example.com/mail/a.php since you are including it in your script. Simply place $name or $more_info wherever you want it to appear in example.com/mail/a.php and it will display.